Return rows with last updated date for different days
Assume this is my PySpark dataframe, ordered by ("ID", "updated_at"):



ID
updated_at
stock_date
row_num




a1
2024-03-25T20:52:36
2024-03-25
1


a1
2024-03-26T11:23:48
2024-03-26
2


a1
2024-03-26T19:25:10
2024-03-26
3


b2
2024-03-24T14:12:20
2024-03-24
4


b2
2024-03-24T20:58:52
2024-03-24
5


b2
2024-03-26T22:24:14
2024-03-26
6


b2
2024-03-28T20:38:38
2024-03-28
7


c3
2024-03-28T15:15:51
2024-03-28
8


c3
2024-03-28T18:11:50
2024-03-28
9


d4
2024-03-24T12:10:15
2024-03-24
10


d4
2024-03-26T21:20:15
2024-03-26
11


d4
2024-03-28T11:55:23
2024-03-28
12


d4
2024-03-28T22:40:34
2024-03-28
13


d4
2024-03-29T11:57:20
2024-03-29
14


d4
2024-03-29T21:48:19
2024-03-29
15



I want to return all rows with the most updated ID of the day, over multiple days.
In other words, if the same ID appears several times in the same day, it must only returns the last time it was updated. If it appears on different days, bring all the occurrences.
Therefore, it would just be the rows: 1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 13 and 15.
I've already created a window function for the most updated date, but I cant figure out how can I separate different days. My table always ends returning the most updated DAY, only.
How can I achieve that?

By separate do you mean group by?

I have one solution, i did it in two steps:
First i am using windows function with paritions by "ID", "stock_date" to get row_number within partition
In second step i am grouping df from first step to get max value for given partition
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number, max, col, first

data = [
    ("a1", "2024-03-25T20:52:36", "2024-03-25", 1),
    ("a1", "2024-03-26T11:23:48", "2024-03-26", 2),
    ("a1", "2024-03-26T19:25:10", "2024-03-26", 3),
    ("b2", "2024-03-24T14:12:20", "2024-03-24", 4),
    ("b2", "2024-03-24T20:58:52", "2024-03-24", 5),
    ("b2", "2024-03-26T22:24:14", "2024-03-26", 6),
    ("b2", "2024-03-28T20:38:38", "2024-03-28", 7),
    ("c3", "2024-03-28T15:15:51", "2024-03-28", 8),
    ("c3", "2024-03-28T18:11:50", "2024-03-28", 9),
    ("d4", "2024-03-24T12:10:15", "2024-03-24", 10),
    ("d4", "2024-03-26T21:20:15", "2024-03-26", 11),
    ("d4", "2024-03-28T11:55:23", "2024-03-28", 12),
    ("d4", "2024-03-28T22:40:34", "2024-03-28", 13),
    ("d4", "2024-03-29T11:57:20", "2024-03-29", 14),
    ("d4", "2024-03-29T21:48:19", "2024-03-29", 15)
]

columns = ['ID', 'updated_at', 'stock_date', 'row_num']
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)

windowSpec  = Window.partitionBy("ID", "stock_date").orderBy("stock_date")
groupedDf = df.withColumn("row_number", row_number().over(windowSpec))

groupedDf.groupBy("ID", "stock_date").agg(
    max('updated_at').alias('updated_at'),
    max('row_num').alias('row_num'),
    max("row_number")
).drop("max(row_number)").show()

output:
+---+----------+-------------------+-------+
| ID|stock_date|         updated_at|row_num|
+---+----------+-------------------+-------+
| a1|2024-03-25|2024-03-25T20:52:36|      1|
| a1|2024-03-26|2024-03-26T19:25:10|      3|
| b2|2024-03-24|2024-03-24T20:58:52|      5|
| b2|2024-03-26|2024-03-26T22:24:14|      6|
| b2|2024-03-28|2024-03-28T20:38:38|      7|
| c3|2024-03-28|2024-03-28T18:11:50|      9|
| d4|2024-03-24|2024-03-24T12:10:15|     10|
| d4|2024-03-26|2024-03-26T21:20:15|     11|
| d4|2024-03-28|2024-03-28T22:40:34|     13|
| d4|2024-03-29|2024-03-29T21:48:19|     15|
+---+----------+-------------------+-------+


thank you a lot, sir! I've thought about partitioning both by id and date, but I couldn't go through with it. thanks again!
